# Needing help understanding cosets of a given vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U\leq V$ be a subspace defined by the plane 8x+2y+5z=0. This implies that $x=-\frac{1}{4}y-\frac{5}{8}z$ and thus u is an element of U iff $u=a(-1/4,1,0)+b(-5/8,0,1)$. Now, to obtain the cosets I define $v=(x,y,z)$ and sum it with the u I obtained, thus giving me:

$$v+U=\{(x-(a/4+5/8b),y+a,z+b)\}$$

With (x,y,z) fixed. Is this a description of a coset? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $v + U = \{(x - a/4 - 5b/8, y+a, z+b) : a,b \in \mathbb R\}$ is technically correct. However, a useful realization that if $U$ is a proper subspace of $V$, then $U$ is a hyperplane in V passing through the origin and $v + U$ translates this plane by $v$, giving us an "affine" hyperplane which might not pass through the origin.

Let us find the equation of the affine plane $v + U$. Put $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$. We have $w = (w_1, w_2, w_3) \in v + U$ if and only if $w - v \in U$ if and only if the equation $8(w_1 - v_1) + 2(w_2 - v_2) + 5(w_3 - v_3) = 0$ is satisfied (by definition of $U$).

So in summary, $v+U$ is the affine plane in $V$ defined by the set of $(x,y,z) \in V$ such that $$8(x - v_1) + 2(y - v_2) + 5(z - v_3) = 0.$$